# Trouble writing controller actions that work with JQuery to update database

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an html table that holds categories of things. Each row consists of a category id and name that are looped in from the model. There are also two buttons in each row. One that I want to use to set the state of the row to enabled and the other to set it to disabled:

```
<table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success categoryEnabled">Enabled</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger categoryDisabled" style="display: none;">Disabled</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I say set to enabled or disabled I mean change the bit value for that row in an SQL table column called state. So, I basically just need the buttons to toggle that bit value for the row in which it is clicked.

Here is where I'm at with the solution:

Here's the Jquery I am using to try to change the bit value for the selected row when each button is clicked:

```
$(".categoryEnabled").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    DisableRow($(this).attr('id'));
});

$(".categoryDisabled").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().show();
    EnableRow($(this).attr('id'));
});

function EnableRow(id) {
    $.post("@Url.Action("DisableRow", "Category")", { "Id": id }, function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        alert('Row Disabled!');
    } else {
        alert('Error disabling row!');
    }
});
}

function DisableRow(id) {
    $.post("@Url.Action("EnableRow", "Category")", { "Id": id }, function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        alert('Row Enabled!');
    } else {
        alert('Error enabling row!');
    }
});
```

You can see that I'm trying to connect these to a controller action in the CategoryController. I am just not too sure what to put into these actions to make the connection to the state column of the Category table using entity framework.

```
public ActionResult DisableRow()
    {

    }

public ActionResult EnableRow()
    {

    }
```

I would also need a loop to identity the row that I'm trying to update:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
string id = "Row" + i.ToString() + "Enable";
i +=1;
}
```

It would also be helpful for you to see the category object as I have it:

```
namespace Rework.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public enum StatesTypes
    {
        Disabled = 0,
        Enabled = 1
    }

public partial class Category
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public StatesTypes state { get; set; }

}
```

}

Db Context:

```
namespace Rework.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class CategoryDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public CategoryDBEntities()
        : base("name=CategoryDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

}

Just not sure if there is a better way or where this would fit in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK firstly your jQuery isn't actually getting an ID. Try updating your code to something like this

```
<table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.id</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-success categoryEnabled" data-id="@item.id">Enabled</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger categoryDisabled" data-id="@item.id" style="display: none;">Disabled</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the ID is part of the button we can access it using the *this* keyword

```
$(".categoryEnabled").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    DisableRow($(this).data('id'));
});

$(".categoryDisabled").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().show();
    EnableRow($(this).data('id'));
});

function EnableRow(id) {
    $.post("@Url.Action('DisableRow', 'Category')", { "Id": id }, function () {

        alert('Row Disabled!');

    }).fail(function() {

        alert('Error disabling row!');
    });
}

function DisableRow(id) {


    $.post("@Url.Action('EnableRow', 'Category')", { "Id": id }, function() {

        alert('Row Enabled!');


    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Error enabling row!');
    });

}
```

Next you need to update your actions. Im not sure why you're returning an ActionResult as it doesn't look like you need any specific response. I don't know what object you use to connect to your database context so you will need to replace this.

```
public void DisableRow(int id)
{

    //
    // Create a instance of your EF database context
    //
    var context = new CategoryDBEntities();

    var record = context.Categories.find(id);

    if (record != null)
    {
        record.state = StateTypes.Disabled;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }


}

public void EnableRow(int id)
{

    //
    // Create a instance of your EF database context
    //
    var context = new CategoryDBEntities();

    var record = context.Categories.find(id);

    if (record != null)
    {
        record.state = StateTypes.Enabled;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did add the dbcontext just to help out.

Comment: I'm getting the error alert when I try to update. Stepping though to figure out what may be going on. The statestypes.enabled and disabled values should have no problem being entered into a bit field, right? I have not used the bit data type in a table before.

Comment: Have you just added this property to your model? You may need to update the database as your model and database will be out of sync. Check out code-migrations and update-database with EF code first. Alternatively if this is a development environment you could just drop & create the db again

Comment: Do you mean added it to my DbContext?

Comment: I meant have you just added the status property to the Category model? If you have then your database and model will be out of sync since this new column will not exist in the database. Was that your error?

Comment: My category model is still the same as in the question. I don't think I fully understand

Comment: @CavanFlynn Apologies I didn't fully read your original comment and have sent you down the wrong route. I'll update the JS so it should work.

Comment: Sorry to keep coming back with issues/questions, but now I'm getting a success alert, but the row is not actually being updated. Hmmmm

Comment: @CavanFlynn Can you debug and step through the actions? Is the record not null and being amended?

Comment: The record variable is not null. It gets the id and name of the table fine. The record.state does change when its supposed to. It just isn't updating the bit value in the db

Comment: I just don't seem to understand how the record.state can change without updating the db